# Unable to send email to gmail accounts in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-mail

I am trying to integrate email(**no_reply@domain.com**) into my Laravel application. I am not using Mailtrap or Google's SMTP. My hosting provider has an email server. I am planning to use that email server.
The problem is that when I send an email from **no_reply@domain.com** to **employee@domain.com** is working. But when sending mail from **no_reply@domain.com** to **test@gmail.com** I didn't get any mail.

**.env file**

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.domail.com
MAIL_PORT="465"
MAIL_USERNAME="no_reply@domain.com"
MAIL_PASSWORD="password"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="no_reply@domain.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

**app/http/controller/EmailController.php**

```
Mail::to('test@gmail.com')->send(new GetStartedMail($request));
```

**app/mail/GetStartedMail.php**

```
public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('no_reply@domain.com', 'No Reply')
            ->subject('New message from '.$this->request->get('name',''))
            ->to('test@gmail.com', $this->request->get('name',''))
            ->markdown('emails.get-started');
    }
```

when i edit those files EmailController.php & GetStartedMail.php of **test@gmail.com** to **employee@domain.com**. I got email from **no_reply@domain.com**

When i mail from outlook (**no_reply@domain.com**) to gmail (**test@gmail.com**) is working**

Can anyone help me understand why I am facing this issue?

Comment: What do you mean that is not working.. you get different from email or you're not receiving the email

Comment: i didn't get email in my Gmail account. I have checked in all folder and spam folder

Comment: If you aren't receiving the email, it means it detected as bounce, you have to check your mail server for gmail response, you will find either 421 or 550 that is mean is detected as SPAM or BOUNCE because your server is not trusted by Gmail (you need to config your DNS ( DKIM, DMARC, SPF, ...) )

Comment: but when I send mail to our outlook (no_reply@domain.com) to gmail(test@gmail.com), I get the mail

Comment: Email Providers are not the same.. each has its rules ! can you please check you email server and show us the feedback you get from Gmail

Answer (score 1):

In order to have google accept your email, you must have an SPF record in your DNS that says your hosting provider is allowed to send email on behalf of the domain.

There are plenty of guides on the internet about SPF records.
I picked this one.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/10685031

You could have an existing SPF record that says ONLY your main mail provider is allowed to send on your behalf.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but via Outlook, mail, or webmail.domain.com is working. only not working in code **Mail::to('test@gmail.com')** . While the service provider checked SPF record was correct.

Comment: You miss the point. The other mail is presumably coming from a different mail provider. You need to tell the world that your web hosting provider can also send email as you.